# Mysql select Query total different in 2 different time

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mysql query to get yesterday's total. It run from CRON and i am getting different total in 3 different time. It run 3 times per day. 
7AM - 6067
12PM - 6670
7PM - 6670

600 different??

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_table` WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ(`reg_date`, '-0:00', '-7:00')) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day)
```

Comment: this query returns "todays" registrations, not yesterdays, so you have ~2k new registrations

Comment: You see INTERVAL -1 day. It should return yesterday's total no? Can you suggest any modification in query?

Comment: you have between `yesterday` and `today`, between is inclusive

Comment: to get yesterdays registrations only use `date(reg_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day)` with additional tz conversion if needed

Comment: Thanks! Lashane issue was on 7AM. So waiting 7AM tomorrow. :)

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_table` WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ(`reg_date`, '-0:00', '-7:00')) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 day) AND `status`='success'

It still return 6067 on 7AM and 6670 10AM... Any idea why different in between 3 hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every time, it depends on your current time. You need to consider only the day.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users_table`
WHERE date(CONVERT_TZ(`reg_date`, '-0:00', '-7:00')) >= DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND date(CONVERT_TZ(`reg_date`, '-0:00', '-7:00')) <= DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: ahh! I tried above query and it return same amount and tried your query and return same amount but different was on morning. I updated query l will check in morning. Hope this solution work.

Comment: @user1464262, I hope so

Comment: Mojtaba It is still return defferent. :P.. no what was issue. I think think query have issue...

Comment: OK. instead of getting the count, try to get reg_date. Then, you can find out your problem with the date and time. the concept of my query is correct. consider the parameters inside CONVERT_TZ